# Which method of document snapshot field access is faster in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully created a query to get data from Firestore. I have this data in my db:

```
- products
   - docId
      - name: "bacon"
      - category: "food"
      - price: 44
```

When I query I get back a QueryDocumentSnapshot and I noticed three ways to get the value of the `name` property. Which is faster and more likely to be used?

```
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                String name = map.get("name").toString(); //First option

                String name = document.getString("name"); //Second option

                Product product = document.toObject(Product.class);
                String name = product.getName(); //Third option
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time the question comes up "which is faster", the answer is always "you should benchmark them to get actual numbers".

But I will say that the practical difference between the first two options is negligible.  They are both essentially constant time map lookups.  You can try to benchmark them, but they will be both so fast it will not matter in practice.  It's my opinion that you shouldn't spend time trying to optimize them.

The third option is always going to be the slowest because the Firestore SDK will have to perform reflection on your model object to find all the setter methods or public fields to map the document field data.  It's the most convenient.  You will save typing time by using toObject, but it will not be as fast.  However, it will probably fast enough, and you still might be wasting your time trying to optimize it.

Bottom line is this: don't spend time optimizing something that doesn't actually measure to be slow.  You're probably spending too much time on it, and it can always be improved later if it is too slow.

Comment: Thank you Doug, I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String name = document.getString("name"); //Second option
```

Its the fastest and memory efficient because there is not any extra object creation part.

Comment: Thank you for answering but what *extra object creation* are you talking? The map from the first option?

Comment: For first option map is the extra object initialization. And for 3rd option product is extra object initialization. These 2 are little time and memory consuming.

Comment: And object initialization is not fast? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: There  needs an extra statement to initialize an object and needs more memory. So 2nd option is less time consuming.